# Satellite 6's puppet is unable to find the hiera data sources

Tags: linux, puppet, foreman, hiera, satellite

Using Satellite 6 which comes with Foreman 1.6.0.53.

By default, Puppetlabs' [documentation](https://puppetlabs.com/blog/debugging-hiera) states that hiera configuration should be in `$config/hiera.yaml`.

```
# puppet config print confdir hiera_config
confdir = /etc/puppet
hiera_config = /etc/puppet/hiera.yaml
```

Looking at our hiera config:

```
# cat /etc/puppet/hiera.yaml
---
:backends: yaml
:yaml:
  :datadir: /var/lib/hiera
:hierarchy:
  - users
  - groups
  - global
```

The data file exists:

```
# cat /var/lib/hiera/users.yaml
---
users:
  bfernandez:
    uid: 300
    fullname: Belmin Fernandez
```

And, to test it, I use hiera's CLI and a `puppet apply`:

```
# hiera --conf=/etc/puppet/hiera.yaml --debug -h users
DEBUG: 2015-05-06 14:11:37 -0400: Hiera YAML backend starting
DEBUG: 2015-05-06 14:11:37 -0400: Looking up users in YAML backend
DEBUG: 2015-05-06 14:11:37 -0400: Looking for data source users
DEBUG: 2015-05-06 14:11:37 -0400: Found users in users
DEBUG: 2015-05-06 14:11:37 -0400: Looking for data source groups
DEBUG: 2015-05-06 14:11:37 -0400: Looking for data source global
{"bfernandez"=>{"uid"=>300, "fullname"=>"Belmin Fernandez"}}

# puppet apply -e '$foo = hiera_hash(users) notify { $foo: }'
Notice: Compiled catalog for foosat.example.com in environment production in 0.08 seconds
Notice: {"bfernandez"=>{"uid"=>300, "fullname"=>"Belmin Fernandez"}}
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Notify[{"bfernandez"=>{"uid"=>300, "fullname"=>"Belmin Fernandez"}}]/message: defined 'message' as '{"bfernandez"=>{"uid"=>300, "fullname"=>"Belmin Fernandez"}}'
Notice: Finished catalog run in 0.30 seconds
```

So far, all looks good. However, when I reference `hiera_hash('users')` in a module and apply it to a node, I get this error:

```
May  6 13:49:04 foo1 puppet-agent[8688]: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Could not find data item users in any Hiera data file and no default supplied at /etc/puppet/modules/accounts/manifests/init.pp:10 on node foo1.example.com
```

Any ideas of what I should look at? Feel like I'm missing something on the Foreman side perhaps.

### Update 1:

Per @lsd, tried using `/etc/hiera.yaml` for the config instead by creating a symlink. Tested it out with hiera CLI to confirm the config:

```
# hiera --conf=/etc/hiera.yaml --debug -h users
DEBUG: 2015-05-06 14:31:13 -0400: Hiera YAML backend starting
DEBUG: 2015-05-06 14:31:13 -0400: Looking up users in YAML backend
DEBUG: 2015-05-06 14:31:13 -0400: Looking for data source defaults
DEBUG: 2015-05-06 14:31:13 -0400: Cannot find datafile /var/lib/hiera/defaults.yaml, skipping
DEBUG: 2015-05-06 14:31:13 -0400: Looking for data source users
DEBUG: 2015-05-06 14:31:13 -0400: Found users in users
DEBUG: 2015-05-06 14:31:13 -0400: Looking for data source groups
DEBUG: 2015-05-06 14:31:13 -0400: Looking for data source global
{"bfernandez"=>{"uid"=>300, "fullname"=>"Belmin Fernandez"}}
```

Still got the error on the agent however so that did not address the issue.

Comment: It is entirely possible that it is trying to user /etc/hiera.yaml instead of /etc/puppet/hiera.yaml.  Everything I've seen has recommended linking /etc/hiera.yaml to /etc/puppet/hiera.yaml.  I'm not saying that is the problem, but you could try that as a first step.

Comment: @lsd Thanks for the suggestion, still getting the error though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After thinking about it on my commute, decided to check out SELinux and there it was:

```
[root@foosat hiera]# grep yaml /var/log/audit/audit.log | head -n1
type=AVC msg=audit(1430926955.728:75727): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=17099 comm="ruby" path="/var/lib/hiera/users.yaml" dev="dm-2" ino=25185161 scontext=system_u:system_r:passenger_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:var_lib_t:s0 tclass=file
```

Changed the file contexts on the hiera file to `puppet_etc_t` (if someone knows of something more appropriate, please comment):

```
[root@foosat hiera]# semanage fcontext -a -s system_u -t puppet_etc_t "/var/lib/hiera(/.*)?"
[root@foosat hiera]# restorecon -R -v .
restorecon reset /var/lib/hiera/users.yaml context unconfined_u:object_r:var_lib_t:s0->unconfined_u:object_r:puppet_etc_t:s0
```

Working now. Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  I have my hieradata in /etc/puppet/hieradata, which has a default context that hiera can read, but of course /var/lib doesn't.

Comment: Sorry to post on an old question, but how are you syncing your hieradata? Is it set up as a repo under Products? Or are you just manually copying it to Satellite/capsules?